# Calling a DLL function from Python

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I want to call a function inside a DLL from Python. But I'm getting this error:

```
"Attribute Error function not found"
```

This is my code:

```
import os
import ctypes


os.chdir("C:\\Program Files\\Compact Automated Testing System V2.0")    

# Load DLL into memory. 
CATSDll = ctypes.WinDLL ("CATS.dll")

# Set up prototype and parameters for the desired function call. 
CATSDllApiProto = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE (ctypes.c_uint8,ctypes.c_double) 

CATSDllApiParams = (1, "p1", 0), (1, "p2", 0), 

# Actually map the call (setDACValue) to a Python name.
CATSDllApi = CATSDllApiProto (("setDACValue", CATSDll), CATSDllApiParams)

# Set up the variables and call the Python name with them. 
p1 = ctypes.c_uint8 (1)
p2 = ctypes.c_double (4)

CATSDllApi(p1,p2)
```

But the DLL documentation shows a function `setDACValue` with `ChannelId` & `DAC Voltage` as the inputs.

The above is based on a piece of code available from StackOverflow.

I've also tried the simple method of using cdll.LoadLibrary & then calling the function, but that also gives the same error.

Can anyone suggest me what is wrong? Thanks.

Full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AEC_FULL\Softwares\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.9.2.201502050007\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 2235, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
  File "C:\Users\AEC_FULL\Softwares\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.9.2.201502050007\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1661, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Users\AEC_FULL\Saravanan\Workspace\CATS\CATS.py", line 18, in <module>
    CATSDllApi = CATSDllApiProto (("setDACValue", CATSDll), CATSDllApiParams)
AttributeError: function 'setDACValue' not found
```

[image: Signature of the setDACValue]

Comment: Could you provide signature of function `setDACValue`?

Comment: Hi kvorobiev ..added the signature..

Answer (score 2):

When you specifiy prototype of function you should specify not only the types of arguments, but the return type as first arg to [WINFUNCTYPE](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/ctypes.html#function-prototypes). Therefore, the line

```
CATSDllApiProto = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE (ctypes.c_uint8,ctypes.c_double)
```

should be replaced with

```
CATSDllApiProto = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE (ctypes.c_uint8, ctypes.c_uint8,ctypes.c_double)
```

Comment: Hi @kvorobiev  thanks for your input...But even after adding that 'm getting the same error.

Comment: @user3561075 Try to use `CFUNCTYPE` instead of `WINFUNCTYPE`

Comment: @user3561075 Could you attach your DLL file, so that I was able to check it?

Comment: I could attach the DLL file but the problem is it is dependent on some additional file which is part of a SW installation. I can share that SW, DLL as well as the documentation if we have some file sharing option.

Comment: @user3561075 To begin with I only need DLL file. You can use any file-sharing services

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76083/discussion-between-user3561075-and-kvorobiev).

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You may need to use `WinDLL`, but `CDLL` is more likely:

```
from ctypes import *

cats = CDLL('CATS')
cats.setDACValue.argtypes = [c_uint8,c_double]
cats.setDACValue.restype = c_uint8

cats.setDACValue(1,4)
```

If it still can't find `setDACValue`, the Microsoft tool `dumpbin` can be used to list the exported functions names in the DLL:

```
dumpbin /exports CATS.dll
```

It comes with Visual Studio installs in the VC\bin directory under the installation.

Comment: Hi @Mark Tolonen :  I tried to to export the functions inside the DLL using DLL Export tool & PE Explorer. I'm not able to get the functions in neither of those tools.